# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my first post and I'm newbie in firebase, sorry if i'm doing some stupid question. Hope you can help me.

This is my bean:

```
public class Fornecedor implements Comparable{
private int id;
private String nome;
private String email;
private int logo;
private Set<Produto> produtos;
private Set<Representante> representantes;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(int logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

public Set<Produto> getProdutos() {
    return produtos;
}

public void setProdutos(HashSet<Produto> produtos) {
    this.produtos = produtos;
}

public Set<Representante> getRepresentantes() {
    return representantes;
}

public void setRepresentantes(HashSet<Representante> representantes) {
    this.representantes = representantes;
}
```

}

This is my firebase data structure:

```
{
  "fornecedores" : {
    "avon" : {
      "email" : "contato@avon.com.br",
      "logo" : "avon.jpg",
      "nome" : "Avon Cosméticos",
      "produtos" : {
        "cremex" : true,
        "perfumex" : true
      },
      "representantes" : {
        "jao" : true,
        "ze" : true
      }
    },
    ... other nodes like above ...
  }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://nasuakz.firebaseio.com/fornecedores");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println("Tem " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " fornecedores");
            for (DataSnapshot fornecedorSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Fornecedor fornecedor = fornecedorSnapshot.getValue(Fornecedor.class);
                System.out.println(fornecedor.getNome() + " - " + fornecedor.getEmail());
            }
        }
```

}

and this is the error that happens on line 7 of above code:
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet

i know that is something wrong with mapping the json to my bean, but this works when i use parcelable, so i'm not understanding why this happen.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ldc8adoNoJ4

Answer (score 2):

Your `produtos` and `representantes` are not sets, but maps. They map a `String` key to a `Boolean` value.

So you need to provide the proper mapping for them:

```
public class Fornecedor implements Comparable{
  private int id;
  private String nome;
  private String email;
  private int logo;
  private Map<String, Boolean> produtos;
  private Map<String, Boolean> representantes;

  public int getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
  public String getNome() { return nome; }
  public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }
  public String getEmail() { return email; }
  public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
  public int getLogo() { return logo; }
  public void setLogo(int logo) { this.logo = logo; }

  public Map<String, Boolean> getProdutos() { return produtos; }

  public Map<String, Boolean> getRepresentantes() { return representantes; }

}
```

You can of course add helper methods to look up the correct `Produto` and `Representante` objects. Just be sure to mark then as `@JsonIgnore`, so that Jackson doesn't try to serialize them.